# Splitting a string by multiple characters (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, split

Ok so I know I can split a string using the .split method every time a character/a sequence of characters appears - for example, in the following code, when I use the .split method, the `<string>` is splitted every time `:` appears in it

```
<string>.split(":")
```

But I can't give it multiple arguments, so that the string is splitted if one of the arguments appears.

For example, given this input string:

```
input_string = """ \ hel\lo ="world"""
```

I want to split the `input_string` every time `\`, `=`, `"`, or `<blank space>` appears, so that i get the following output:

```
['hel', 'lo', 'world']
```

I know that a solution for this could be:

```
non_alfanumeric = """\\=" """
input_string = """ \ hel\lo ="world"""

for char in non_alfanumeric:
    input_string = input_string.replace(char, " ")

list = input_string.split(" ")
while "" in list:
    list.remove("")
```

but this would be too much computationally slow if the input string is very long, because the code has to check the whole string 4 times: first time for `\`, second time for `=`, third time for `"`, fourth time for `<blank space>`.

What are other solutions?

Comment: `re.split('[\\\\=" ]', text)` ?

Comment: @furas perfect! thank you very much. One question: why did you put the square brackets before the characters in '[\\\\="]'?

Comment: https://trinket.io/python3/43e0da34c2

Comment: you have to remove empty strings - you can use `filter` with `None` - `list(filter(None, re.split('[\\\\=" ]', text)))`

Comment: @furas yeah ok this works even better, thanks. I'm new to StackOverflow, is there a way I can give you points by upvoting your comment or something?

Comment: regex use `[ ]` to create list of chars - without `[ ]` it will treat it as single word

Comment: question is closed so I can't add answer - you can only upvote my comments (if you only will have enough reputation/points to do this).

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at regex splitting, something like

```
import re

[x for x in re.split(r'[= \\"]+', """ \ hel\lo ="world""") if x]
```

Comment: ...`if x.strip()`

Comment: I don't think that is required, any x that evaluates to true will not have any white space characters since that is one of the characters the poster wants to split on.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that [re.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) will be good for your case.